# How to access total items outside v-data-table in vuetify.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have just migrated `vuetify.js` from 1.5 to 2.1.7. Previously I was able to access total no. of items (reactive) in the data-table outside of `v-data-table` using `:pagination.sync="pagination"` props and accessing with `pagination.totalItems`.

#### Vuetify 1.5

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span>Total: {{ pagination.totalItems }}</span>
        <v-data-table :pagination.sync="pagination" :items="items">
            ...
        </v-data-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "LoadTable",
        data() {
            return {
              items: [...],
              pagination: {}
            };
        }
   }
</script>
```

But in version 2.x, pagination prop has been removed and replaced with options instead with breaking changes and couldn't able to access the total no. of items. Is there any way in version 2 to access total items which sync with search and filter?

Answer (score 1):

`<v-data-table>` has an event named `pagination`. You can use the event to update your current `pagination` property unless you want to override pagination options.

Try to use it in this way:

```html
<v-data-table :items="items" @pagination="pagination = $event">
```

This will synchronize pagination property each time there is a change on pagination options.

```js
// Pagination object
{
  page: number
  itemsPerPage: number
  pageStart: number
  pageStop: number
  pageCount: number
  itemsLength: number
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) under `Events` tab.